# Clearing form values when insert fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've inherited a ASP.NET web forms (.NET 2) project that makes extensive use of the DetailsView and BoundFields to handle inserting and updating data. On failed inserts however it isn't retaining any of the data entered on the form and I can't see how I can get it to.  The pattern used by my previous colleague is:

- Open edit.aspx?ID=123 which is defaulted to the Detailsview mode of edit
- If ID is empty and not a postback change the Detailsview mode to insert
- Complete the form and wire the onItemInserting to a validation method
- In the validation method validate, populate any error labels on error and cancel the event when in error

The fields aren't generated dynamically. I have tried to manually populate the values in the code behind by changing the nullDisplayText on the bound field.  I've converted the bound fields to Template fields and again in the code behind update the text attribute on the textboxes they produce.

Errors are showing without fault when cancelling the insert event, but I cannot get the form either to retain values or populate the fields when lifting posted data from the event.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether ViewState have been disabled for that page or globally in web.config. Also check the same for the specific control.

Comment: Hi, viewstate wasn't enabled, however enabling it on the page and the control and unfortunately it still isn't keeping the values.